# How to save parse User object into pointer field of another class via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, parse-platform

I've got a parse.com user's objectId and am using that to query for the user object, which works great!  I then want to store a reference to that user object over in another parse.com class.  Here is my code.

```
            function followThisPlayer(pid, creeper) {

                alert(creeper + " is about to follow " + pid);  // prints:  c9NttiB1Ot is about to follow i5MffYMe6d

                var newFollowRelationship = new Parse.Object("playerAndFollowers");
                var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
                query.equalTo("playerId", pid);
                query.first({
                    success: function (object) {
                        var playerPtr = new Parse.User();
                        playerPtr = object;
                        newFollowRelationship.set("playerPointer", playerPtr);
                        newFollowRelationship.set("playerId", pid);
                        newFollowRelationship.set("creeperId", creeper);
                        newFollowRelationship.save();
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        response.error("movie lookup failed");
                    }
                });

            }
```

Notice that the playerId and creeperId are both written to the new class.  However, the playerPtr is not written.  The target value of type 'Pointer' remains undefined.

[image]
What the heck?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, nothing wrong with the code...  The equalTo part of the query needed to reference "objectId" instead of "playerId"...  Brain fart.

Comment: So do you set your player pointer column to be the whole user object? Or do you only pass in the user's `objectId` as a string?